# Comparing 2 ul list item in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How we compare (comparing through class) 2 ul listitems through jquery, i can do this through loops but i want the best way to do this ( using some jquery method)?

Comment: Compare them in what way? `text()`, `length`, `height()`... work with us here.

Comment: comparing in text() , number of items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:   http://jsfiddle.net/AzZHy/

You will create a master list and then compare,

**jquery code**

```
var master = [];

// Identify the master values.
$('ul').first().find('li').each(function(index,value) {
    master.push($(this).text());
});

$('ul:not(:first)').each(function(ulIndex) {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(index) {
        if(master[index] != $(this).text()) {
            $(this).addClass('mismatch');        
        }  
    });
});​
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>hulk</li>
    <li>ironman</li>
    <li>bazinga</li>
    <li>thor</li>
    <li>rambo</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul>
    <li>hulk</li>
    <li>ironman</li>
    <li>Zooyork</li>
    <li>thor</li>
    <li>rambo</li>
</ul>
<br/>

​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = $(...), list2 = $(...);
```

To compare the lengths, use `list1.length` and `list2.length`.
To compare the texts of the elements, the easiest way might be storing them in arrays:

```
var texts1 = list1.children('li').map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
var texts2 = list2.children('li').map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
```